# Need to know which day-of-week is represented by the DateTime object

Tags: apex, datetime

I'm using the DateTime object in my apex code.

In the documentation of the DateTime class I saw there are methods to return day-of-month, day-of-year but there is no method to return day-of-week what I need.

I need to know which day-of-week is represented by this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only practical way to get this is to use the format method:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
```